# If statement on background X position in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, background-position

```
if(  $mouse.css('background-position-x') >= "-600") {
 $mouse.css('background-position-x','-=40');
};
```

^ is the code I'm trying to run. I have this in a game loop so I essentially want to animate the background position but only as far as -600px on the X axis. This doesn't seem to work, any ideas for an alternate solution??

Comment: `$mouse.css('background-position-x','-=40');` is setting the style to the string literal of `-=40`. You can't use the `-=` operator like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
var x = parseInt($mouse.css('background-position-x'));
if( x >= -600 ) {
   $mouse.css('background-position-x', x - 40);
};
```

would work.

Please try, untested.

Comment: Thanks. The actual function didnt run but the if statement did perfectly. So i merged my function and your if statement.

Comment: @WalterStabosz did a great job updating. Did you try before or after ( the x variable )? Great anyway!!

Comment: No I did not test the code in either form. I just refactored yours to use a variable to be more readable. But it will probably work.

Comment: @WalterStabosz Hi, no, great job. Except mentioning you and rewarding you the rest of the message was for bboybeatle though. %)P

Answer (score 1):

`background-position-x` is not standard way in css. So, do like this:

```
if(  $mouse.css('background-position').split(' ')[0] >= "-600") {
 $mouse.css('background-position','-=40 '+ $mouse.css('background-position').split(' ')[1]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive heard that before I will look at modifying what ive got to avoid x and y